# "sed" transform one parameter in one duplicated paragraph

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I've got to parse a file that contains several information. such as:

```
... some configs
CONFIGURATION = {
    "MASTER": "VALUE",
    "WORKER": "VALUE"
}

CONFIGURATION_RECENT = {
    "MASTER": "VALUE",
    "WORKER": "VALUE"
}
... some others configs
```

I would like to be able to update independently the WORKER value that is in CONFIGURATION and the one that is in CONFIGURATION_RECENT.

the only value we can rely on is "CONFIGURATION" and "CONFIGURATION" and the keys WORKER and MASTER.. values can change.

Do you think it could be possible to update it with a sed command? or maybe a awk. I'm currently working under Ubuntu.

Thanks a lot for your help
Thomas

Comment: You are expected to perform basic research and make an effort. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: provide your solution attempt, and sample output

Comment: Thanks for your very helping answers, I actually know how to sed"s@mySentence@NewSentence@", but I don't know how to perform this substitution based on a paragraph ref 2 or n lines above. I had in mind to read all lines form my file, when the CONFIGURATION is found, then parse the below lines until }  is not found, but it looks quite complicated for a so small operation..  I just needed to have a clue on the syntax. Being ironic to not help people is not the goal of stack overflow I guess. I don't do it when I try to help other people. Thanks a lot for your non help.

Comment: Sorry jww it looks basic for you. But not for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash and GNU sed:

```
section_start="^CONFIGURATION ="
section_end="^}"
key="WORKER"
new_value="foobar42"

sed -r "/${section_start}/,/${section_end}/{s/(\"${key}\": \").*(\")/\1${new_value}\2/}" file
```

Output:

```
... some configs
CONFIGURATION = {
    "MASTER": "VALUE",
    "WORKER": "foobar42"
}

CONFIGURATION_RECENT = {
    "MASTER": "VALUE",
    "WORKER": "VALUE"
}
... some others configs
```

`$new_value` should not contain any characters that `sed` could interpret as a command.

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858) and `man sed`

Comment: Whaou, this is awesome. Thanks a lot

Comment: I've read the section concerning grouping. thanks a lot for this.
May I ask for 1 explanation in your sed command?

I understand that :
#sed -r "/${section_start}/,/${section_end}/{s@\"WORKER\".*@\"WORKER\": \"${new_value}\"@}"  file

is equivalent to:

sed -r "/${section_start}/,/${section_end}/{s/(\"${key}\": \").*(\")/\1${new_value}\2/}" file.

in other words why does your group *(\") corresponds to?
does it mean that any char after the ${key} will be copied in the substituted part?

Comment: This example may be clearer without all the backslashes and `"`: `echo "Hello world" | sed -r 's/(.*) (.*)/\1 my \2/'` This section might help: [Back-references and Subexpressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html)

Comment: from what I can understand in your example and the doc:
"(.*) " >>> first packet until space: Hello
(.*)  >>> second packet: world
===> ??? 1 contains Hello and 2 contains world?
so, the second part should substitute "world" with my...
Why does my comes before world?
why does: {echo "Hello world TOTO" | sed -r 's@(.*) (.*)@\1 my \2@'
returns Hello world my TOTO}.
Sorry for all those questions

Comment: In my example `Hello world` is split with regex `(.*) (.*)` in two parts separated with one space. First part (`Hello`) is referenced by \1 and second part (`world`) by \2. The space between `Hello world` is not referenced. \1 my \2/` produce then `Hello my world`. In your example `Hello world` is referenced by \1 and second part `TOTO` by \2. [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-regular-expressions) might help with understanding regex and  [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it's almost cristal clear now. In my example it considers the 2nd space as delimiter because sed is greedy right?

Comment: Yes, rexgex (`*`) is normaly greedy. It is possible to simulate non-greedy this way: `echo "Hello world TOTO" | sed -r 's@([^ ]*) (.*)@\1 my \2@'`. Perl's rexgex (e.g.) can switch to non-greedy with `?` after `*`: `echo "Hello world TOTO" | perl -pe 's@(.*?) (.*)@\1 my \2@'`